# Cordova HttpClient IOS failure response

Tags: ios, vue.js, cordova, svg, xmlhttprequest

I developed an application on vuejs using inline svg with the svg-inline plugin. When I build the app with cordova on android the inline svg are displayed but on IOS it doesn't work. In the logs I have the following error message: "object xmlhttprequestprogressevent"

Has anyone ever had this problem?

thank you in advance.